# UICollectionViewCell with self-sizing vertically according to amount of text in Universal app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I am an amateur iOS developer. I have made a simple Single Window Universal app in iOS to demonstrate my problem. In interface builder, I added the UICollectionView to my view and gave it specific constraints to cover entire screen. Then I made a prototype cell and gave it width of 580 and height of 80 using utilities panel. And added a label to this cell and gave constraints in interface builder itself.

[image]

Now, if I run this project (simulator device iPhone 6), the width of cell is not adjusted according to the screen of device. It goes outside the screen and appears as follows:

[image]

```
This thing also gives me following messages in the console while running the project:

2015-11-10 11:11:15.688 uicillectionview auto-sizing[3338:262762] the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
2015-11-10 11:11:15.689 uicillectionview auto-sizing[3338:262762] the item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values, minus the content insets left and right values.
2015-11-10 11:11:15.689 uicillectionview auto-sizing[3338:262762] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7f981176f810>, and it is attached to <UICollectionView: 0x7f9811862400; frame = (0 20; 375 647); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7f981176e860>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9811586a60>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {600, 0}> collection view layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7f981176f810>.
2015-11-10 11:11:15.689 uicillectionview auto-sizing[3338:262762] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
```

Now, if I add following lines of code to `ViewController.m`, the CollectionView appears completely fine without giving any error in console:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-20.0, 80);

}
```

After adding the above code and running the project, the width is adapted perfectly according to device screen size as follows:
[image]

I want to achieve achieve functionality so that the CollectionViewCell adjust height of cell according to the size off variable text to fit it completely and width according to the device screen width. Can somebody please help?

Comment: don't choose "equal" value for UILable constraint . use "greater than"

Comment: for all constraints of label? @engmahsa

Comment: no just for height constraint

Comment: and also don't use data source for equal height of cell

Comment: Did not work. The text is going out of the cell from top as well as bottom of cell.

Comment: yes it works . now we have the real size of UILabel . then we have to edit the data source

Comment: did you implement height for row with "equal" parameter?

Comment: It is collection view so how can I set height of its cell with equal parameter? If interface builder, then where?

Comment: try this -> return [cell systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94678/discussion-between-engmahsa-and-the-rohan-sanap).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just calculate the height of a text. Here is method.

```
func heightForView(text:String, font:UIFont, width:CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
        let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, CGFloat.max))
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
        label.font = font
        label.text = text
        label.sizeToFit()
        return label.frame.height
    }
```

Then u can use like this

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let cellWidth = self.view.frame.size.width
        let cellHeight = heightForView("Your Text", font: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17), width: cellWidth)

        return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)
    }
```

Comment: for "width" which value should I use? Screen width or the desired width of my cell? ( desired width of my cell is screenWidth-20 )

Comment: desired width of your cell